# Finding maximum value from a table

Tags: sql, max, multiple-columns

I have a table named TestValue like bellow

```
value1  value2  value3
10      19      17
78      8       91
```

I want to get the maximum value. I have tried this query in SQL:

```
select (select MAX(v) from (values (Value1),(Value2),(Value3)) as value(v)) 
      as Maxvalue 
      from TestValue
```

it results like

```
Maxvalue
19
91
```

but I want the result to be only `91`.

Comment: or Oracle? or PostgreSQL? or DB2?

Comment: I know thia is a sample, but it's usually an indication that the data modelling is wrong in the first place if you have *multiple* columns containing data that represents the same type of thing (such that comparisons between them even make sense)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS SQL Server doesn't have a `GREATEST` function, but you can simulate it with a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT MAX(
    CASE
        WHEN value1 > value2 And value1 > value3 THEN value1
        WHEN value2 > value3 THEN value2
        ELSE value3
    END) AS Maxvalue FROM TestValue
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with `greatest` is good, but it depends on db-specific solution (e.g. as far as I know on SQL Server you don't have something like `greatest`) so you can use generic one:

```
SELECT MAX(v) FROM
(
  SELECT value1 v FROM tab
  UNION ALL
  SELECT value2 v FROM tab
  UNION ALL
  SELECT value3 v FROM tab
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works ([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43030/1)):

```
SELECT max(greatest(value1, value2, value3))
FROM testvalue
```

**EDIT:**
`greatest()` is supported on all popular servers (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle), but not on MSSQL. For MSSQL, it is common to create stored procedure to [simulate this function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic371131-9-1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f1d49/5)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
create table TestValue
(
  value1 int,
  value2 int,
  value3 int
);

insert into TestValue values(10,      19,      17);
insert into TestValue values(78,      8 ,      91);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select max(MaxValue) as MaxValue
from
(
  select (select MAX(v) from (values (Value1),(Value2),(Value3)) as value(v)) 
        as Maxvalue 
        from TestValue
) as T
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f1d49/5/0)**:

```
| MAXVALUE |
------------
|       91 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select max(Value) as MaxValue
from TestValue 
unpivot (Value for Col in (Value1, Value2, Value3)) as U
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f1d49/5/1)**:

```
| MAXVALUE |
------------
|       91 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(max(Value1),max(Value2),max(Value3)) from Persons
```

tested [here](http://ideone.com/aUzeFk)